# change parent of child if isset submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pdo

When the page loaded it will displayed the family tree from DB into list like this and inside each child there is link(change Parent).

```
John
   Jack *change parent*
       Husam *change parent*
   Koko *change parent*
       Rami *change parent*
       Loay *change parent*
```

And I have dropdown that have all parent and child, if I click on change parent inside Husam for example it will make his father (Jack) in dropdown selected option, when I change his parent from dropdown to Rami for example and click save submit I want to move Husam under Remi and remove it from under Jack.

This query to get parent od child in dropdown when I clicked on link

```
function changeParent() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a").click(function() {
            function getEventTarget(e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                return e.target || e.srcElement;
            }
            var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('listSet');
            [].forEach.call(ul, function(el) {
                el.onclick = function(event) {
                    var target = getEventTarget(event);
                    //alert(target.id);
                    document.getElementById('names').value = target.id;
                    $("#save").show();
                };
            });
        });
    });
}
```

And this code echo the parent when I clicked save to test submit, what I should write here to do this process??

```
 if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
      $selected = $_POST['parent'];
      echo "You have selected :".
      " ".$selected;
  }
```

Then the output will be like this

```
John
   Jack *change parent*
   Koko *change parent*
       Rami *change parent*
           Husam *change parent*
       Loay *change parent*
```

Comment: Can you show us the output according to your action please, it's not very clear for me :s

Comment: If the submit action reloads the page, then the new page will render the new tree, so there is no need to use JavaScript for that.

Comment: @MickaelLeger i added the output please check

Comment: @Dormilich I' am fresh self learner please explain more.

Comment: @H.Ghass It looks like you use a regular form submit to change the parent. This means that the page reloads and in this case the new tree data are passed to the template. Hence there is nothing to do for JavaScript.

Comment: @Dormilich So how i can solve my problem sir ?

Comment: 2 possibilities I think according to what you want : 1/ You want to keep the new parent - child relation after the reload? => Add the information in database so after reload you will have what you want 2/ You only want the change after submit and on reload you come back to the original relation? => use Ajax to change the content without reloading the page

Comment: @H.Ghass The problem, which isn't there?

Comment: @MickaelLeger the second thing what i want ... but i need some help please i need some resource to learn how i can change the parent of specific <li> from dropdown

Comment: @H.Ghass well, I just realise you don't need to use PHP if you just want to change some html content, so just replace your submit button by a button type button and on click you use your function. Or try `$("form").submit(function(e){        e.preventDefault(); /* the code to change the parent */ });`. The idea is just to stop the submit so you won't reload the page

Comment: My problem not just to stop reload the page ... my problem i need help in part  /* the code to change the parent */  i don't have this code and my question to find some one help me in this part sir :D @MickaelLeger

Comment: Do you want at some point to save the changed tree structure to the server?

Comment: Yes , can you check my question here sir ?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816072/from-url-set-parent-selected-option @Dormilich

Comment: In that case I recommend something along react+redux, since changing the underlying data is much easier than changing the DOM (and these types of libraries do the heavy lifting of changing the DOM according to the data).

Comment: I will reading about it. please can you check the link ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50816072/from-url-set-parent-selected-option

Comment: How i can retrieve $output['parent'] in ajax Sir ?